# Prevent auto scrolling when clicking tab anchor in wpui and FF17

Tags: jquery, wordpress, anchor

On my page I have some tabs that I've added some javascript so when they're clicked the page loads the tab's anchor URL instead of simply changing the view with AJAX, but I now want to stop the browser from auto scrolling to the anchor location.

Having done some research, I'm pretty sure I just need to add a couple of lines so that when clicked it returns false or prevents default but, being a noob, I've no idea where to put them!?!

I know it's cheeky, but if any answers could include the full script (ie. the below) with the solution, that way I'll understand better and hopefully learn some valuable lessons also :)

Here's the code I'm using:

```
jQuery( function() {
   jQuery('.ui-tabs').bind( 'tabsselect', function( e, ui ) {
         window.location.hash = ui.tab.hash });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor jump happens because it is default behavior. To prevent this from happening you may need to do the following `event.preventDefault()`. I dont know my way around wpui.js but you can always ask in the [support forums](http://kav.in/forum/discussions/tagged/tabs).

**Update**
OP provides website with problems in comments http://immaga.com/wills
Works in chrome 23.0.1271.91, FF 16.0.1 *but not* in FF 17.0

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortuantely when I add that code, the tab links no longer work and it still scrolls to the anchor point.

Comment: could you provide more code - e.g. the html element containing the tabs and code corresponding to the initialization/setup of the tabs

Comment: Now i am confused, there is no anchor jump happening ?! Did you mean the footer which jumps up in order the fill the free space ?

Comment: It is for me, I'm using FF 17.0 and the top of the page scrolls down to the top of the Tabs, so no header or navigation is showing on click.

Comment: This is a bug in WP-UI from kav.in and i only encounter it on FF 17 ( i tested chrome, FF16 and safari )

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks for all of your help! No wonder I couldn't solve it!!